# Java: Filter items that are comparable to a wildcard type

Tags: java, generics, casting, wildcard, instanceof

I'm writing an interpreter for a DSL and I ran into a problem where I want to compare two values of unknown type. I have tried to reduce the problem to the following.

I want to define a function with two parameters with the following specification.

```java
public boolean isMinimumOrThrow(Object minToCheck, Collection<Object> coll);
```

1. If `minToCheck` is not of type `Comparable<?>`, then I want to throw a runtime exception.
2. Otherwise, I want to filter out all objects in `coll` that I can compare with `minToCheck`, and then return whether `minToCheck` is less than or equal to every comparable object in `coll`.

### First attempt

I get in trouble when defining the filter, i.e.,

```java
public boolean isMinimumOrThrow(Object minToCheck, Collection<Object> coll) {
    if (!(minToCheck instanceof Comparable<?>)) {
        throw new RuntimeException();
    }
    Comparable<?> comparableMin = (Comparable<?>)minToCheck;
    return coll.stream().filter(...).allMatch(item -> comparableMin.compareTo((...)item) <= 0);
}
```

I'm not sure whether it's possible to implement the `...`.

### Second attempt

To work around the problem, I've tried to loosen the restriction of `Comparable` a bit, and defined my own interface `MyComparable<T>`

```java
public interface MyComparable<T> extends Comparable<T> {
    public Collection<T> filterComparable(Collection<?> values);
}
```

but even then, I still get a type error

```
The method compareTo(capture#13-of ?) in the type Comparable<capture#13-of ?> is not applicable for the arguments (capture#12-of ?)
```

with the following code

```java
public boolean isMinimumOrThrow(Object minToCheck, Collection<Object> coll) {
    if (!(minToCheck instanceof MyComparable<?>)) {
        throw new RuntimeException();
    }
    MyComparable<?> comparableMin = (MyComparable<?>)minToCheck;
    return comparableMin.filterComparable(coll).stream().allMatch(item -> comparableMin.compareTo(item) <= 0);
}
```

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe there is a cleaner solution, but you could stick to your first attempt. The filter can be implemented by simply trying a `compareTo` in a try-catch. This in turn only compiles if you use raw `Comparable` in intermediate steps. The result will be typesafe again (I hope), but needs to suppress some warnings for the intermediate steps. So my suggestion is the following:

```
@SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
public static boolean isMinimumOrThrow(Object minToCheck, Collection<Object> coll) {
    if (!(minToCheck instanceof Comparable)) {
        throw new RuntimeException();
    }
    @SuppressWarnings("rawtypes")
    Comparable comparableMin = (Comparable)minToCheck;
    return coll.stream().filter(item -> {
        boolean isComparable = true;
        try {
            comparableMin.compareTo(item);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            isComparable = false;
        }

        return isComparable;
    }).allMatch(item -> comparableMin.compareTo(item) <= 0);
}

public static void main(String[] args) {
    Collection<Object> list = Arrays.asList("bla",5,"blub",2,7);

    System.out.println("Is 0 minimum: " + isMinimumOrThrow(0, list)); // true
    System.out.println("Is 2 minimum: " + isMinimumOrThrow(2, list)); // true
    System.out.println("Is 3 minimum: " + isMinimumOrThrow(3, list)); // false
    System.out.println("Is 'bla' minimum: " + isMinimumOrThrow("bla", list)); // true
    System.out.println("Is 'blub' minimum: " + isMinimumOrThrow("blub", list)); // false
    System.out.println("Is 'some object' minimum: " + isMinimumOrThrow(new Object(), list)); // throws RuntimeException

}
```

Comment: Hmm, I dislike the usage of raw types and "ducktyping" bit, but this definitely satisfies all my requirements. :)

Comment: yes, I have the same feelings. Maybe someone will find a nicer way. I'm still glad it does the job : )

Answer (score 0):

I did a couple of minor changes to your code and I believe I got the function working as you wanted.

First I defined the function as generic:

```
<T> boolean isMinimumOrThrow(T minToCheck, Collection<T>)
```

And I simplified a little bit your filter and added a cast to T on item:

```
coll.stream().allMatch(item -> comparableMin.compareTo( (T) item) <= 0);
```

This is using standard Comparable. Your main problem I think was missing the cast on "item".

A full working example with integers:

```
import java.util.Collection;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.lang.Comparable;
public class Program
{
    static <T> boolean isMinimumOrThrow(T minToCheck, Collection<T> coll) {
        if (!(minToCheck instanceof Comparable<?>)) {
            throw new RuntimeException();
        }
        Comparable<T> comparableMin = (Comparable<T>) minToCheck;
        return coll.stream().allMatch(
                item -> comparableMin.compareTo( (T) item) <= 0
            );
    }
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        boolean isMinimum = false;

        Collection<Integer> list = Arrays.asList(1,2,3,4,5);
        
        isMinimum = isMinimumOrThrow(0, list);
        System.out.println("Is minimum: " + isMinimum);
        
    }
}
```

Comment: Please first try your code before submitting an answer. You cannot cast to a generic type `T`, so this doesn't compile.

Comment: Also, the essential difficulty I'm having has to do with filtering the collection to only items of the appropriate type. Among else, you are casting `minToCheck` to `Comparable<T>`, which is unsafe. You only know it's a `Comparable<?>`, and by doing the unsafe cast, you're kindof ignoring the problem I'm having.

For example, suppose the type `T` is some custom class `MyObject` that implements the interface `Comparable<String>`, then your code will get into trouble.